# How an I see what percentage of viewers watch to the end of my YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, analytics

I'm trying to figure out if my video demo is too long.

So I'd like to see how many people watch 100% of it.

I can see the analtics and it shows estimated time watched.

My calculations show that  # Minutes-watched/Length  = about 3/4 the # of viewers.

So.... looks like not everyone watches to the end. But if 70% of people watch to the end and 30% of people watch 5 seconds then it's not too long (the first 5 seconds might be too boring..)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- In Video Manager, open your video.
- Click the "Analytics" button.
- Click on the small "Performance" chart.
- Set "Compare Metric" to "Average percentage viewed".
- Maybe change the date range to, say, "This Quarter".

The chart will show the average percentage viewed for each day, and above the chart, the overall average percentage viewed. This is close to what you wanted. If there's only one view per X coordinate, the report will reveal what % of the video was watched in that view.

I think you can get fine-grained data via the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/).

Comment: That gets close. I'll wait and see if anyone can find a way to get exactly what I need. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Analytics > Audience Retention is very helpful

[image]